# how to get the first day and the last of previous month using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get the first day of last month like 01/01/2013, also i want to get the last day of previous month like 01/31/2013.  If we are in March then i want to do the same thing like 02/01/2013 and 02/28/2013 and so on....
thanks

Comment: have a look at this [SQL First and Last Day Of a Month](http://sqltutorials.blogspot.de/2007/06/sql-first-and-last-day-of-month.html)

Comment: also this: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/18/sql-server-find-last-day-of-any-month-current-previous-next/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This should do it:

```
--First day of last month
SELECT DATEADD(m,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()), 0))
--Last day of last month
SELECT DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First and last day of previous month:

   ```
   DATEADD ( DAY , 1 , EOMONTH ( GETDATE ( ) , - 2 ) ) 
   EOMONTH ( GETDATE ( ) , - 1 )
   ```
2. First and last day of current month:

   ```
   DATEADD ( DAY , 1 , EOMONTH ( GETDATE ( ) , - 1 ) )
   EOMONTH ( GETDATE ( ) , 0 )
   ```
3. First and last day of next month:

   ```
   DATEADD ( DAY , 1 , EOMONTH ( GETDATE ( ) , 0 ) )
   EOMONTH ( GETDATE ( ) , 1 )
   ```
4. First and last day of Nth month:

   ```
   DATEADD ( DAY , 1 , EOMONTH ( GETDATE ( ) , N-1 ) )
   EOMONTH ( GETDATE ( ) , N )
   ```

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution

```
DECLARE @Today DATETIME
SELECT @Today = GETDATE()

  update  Test.dbo.DateTable
  set StartDate = (
SELECT convert (varchar, DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@Today))-1),DATEADD(mm,-1,@Today)),101))

update Test.dbo.DateTable
set EndDate = (
SELECT convert(varchar, DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,@Today)), DATEADD(m,0,@Today)),101))
```

Answer (score 0):

**First day of the last month**

```
convert (date,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0))
```

**Last Day of the previous month**

```
convert (date,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code works in SQL Server

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), (DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)), 1) [First day] /*First date of previous month*/
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), (DATEADD(s, - 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0))), 1) [Last day] /*Last date of previous month*/
```

Answer (score -1):

The following query works to find the last day of the prior month in my older MySQL:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL Extract(DAY from now()) DAY);
```

Comment: question is tagged "SQL Server"