# SQL Dynamically datetime change

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Every month i run the following query

```
select A.a,    
from A
inner join B on .....
where  B.RemDate between '2013/09/01' and '2013/10/01'
```

I want to add it as a Job (from the SQL Server Agent) to run every 2nd day of the month.
Is it possible to automatically change the

```
B.RemDate between '2013/09/01' and '2013/10/01'
```

to

```
B.RemDate between '1stday_of_previous_month' and '1st_day_of_current_month'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144964/how-to-get-the-first-day-and-the-last-of-previous-month-using-sql

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? If 2012 - there is a function [`EOMONTH()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213020.aspx) to get last day of month and using it easily to get the first also (DATEADD -1). If not check the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function like

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnFirstDayOfMonth]
    (@date AS DATETIME)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @d AS DATETIME
    SET @d = (DATEADD(dd, -(DAY(@date)-1), @date))
    RETURN CAST(@d AS DATE)
END
```

Then

```
select A.a,    
from A
inner join B on .....
where  B.RemDate between dateadd(M,-1,dbo.fnFirstDayOfMonth(getdate())) 
                     and dbo.fnFirstDayOfMonth(getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method

To get the first day of the previos month
select GETDATE(), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)

To get the first day of the current month
select GETDATE(), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, '2013-06-10'), 0)

having for your query

```
select A.a,    
from A
inner join B on .....
where  B.RemDate between DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) and DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, '2013-06-10'), 0)
```

I used this topic -> [How to get first and last day of previous month (with timestamp) in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743810/how-to-get-first-and-last-day-of-previous-month-with-timestamp-in-sql-server)

Hope this helps